# Article voting with feedback option

Tags: 7, rating

I am attempting to setup an article voting system with the ability to provide feedback to the author. Only admins will be able to see feedback so I do not want it like a review attached at the bottom of each article. My idea was to create a view that only admins had permission to see. Include in this view would be the article name, rating, and feedback if any was submitted. I would like to be able to group the feedback/ratings by article instead of by entry or user and provide an overall calculated rating for the article.

It looks like [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) is able to do some of this however I do not believe the [advanced instructions:"Configuration as a CCK field / Advanced Rating"](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/fivestar) are for drupal 7. I have created a content type of "Article Feedback" and attempted to follow [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5464/10551) of how to set something similar up however I do not see anywhere when I create the rating field a "voting target". I do not really understand how Node Reference works and how it will work with the desired result I stated at the beginning of this question.

I am open to using different modules and writing my own PHP script to accomplish this task. Any direction on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the built in drupal comment system as the feedback and just hid the comments from everyone but admins. I used fivestar for the star rating system attached to comments.